# Google Sheets API for clickable images in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In Google sheets, you can insert a clickable image to a cell which links to a function in app script. Can we also insert this clickable image and link it to app script from our server using Google Spreadsheet API? Or Can we call app script from our server?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we also insert this clickable image and link it to app script from our server using Google Spreadsheet API?

No. You can't even change the color of a cell. The best you can do is change a formula in a cell.

> Or Can we call app script from our server?

Yes, use google-apps-script HTML service. I expect you can insert your "clickable image" with google-apps-script as well, but did not check.